# BAD REQUEST 400, when trying to access JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I've been working on a bot for `Discord` in `discord.py` (not related) and I'm trying to pull from a server so I can interpret it, however, I'm getting a

> BAD REQUEST 400

when trying to actually pull from the server. I've tried to add a header to specify it as a JSON but it won't work.

```
await bot.say("Fetching data")
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
url = 'http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=boushi'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
await bot.say(response)
```

The `bot.say` is just repeating back to me the output.

Comment: Simple `requests.get(url).json()` works just fine for me.

Comment: And you are sure this file exists at this url and displays OK? What happens when you put it in a browser? It loads with a 200?

Comment: @niemmi tried this, of course that was just what was placed with the bot.say and yet still no response

Comment: @TheBrewmaster Loads perfectly http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=boushi

Comment: Tried a few different JSON websites, one threw a BAD REQUEST (original jisho), tried another website for the time threw and error because of the charset I believe (not accepting '-') and the final http://ip.jsontest.com/ displayed the IP correctly, is it how that I am attempting to access the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use .json() at the end of the request, in case you want to check the status_code for a bad request first.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print response.content
```

And if you want to do something with the dict you can use json.loads()

```
foo = json.loads(response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That worked quite well and some data is now responding, however, I cannot get the Japanese Characters to display correctly, how can I do this?

Comment: You would need to loop through the dict and encode the Japanese characters with utf-8 
e.g. print u'\u307c\u3046\u3057'.encode('utf8')